# How to implement own HTTP(S) proxy pool based API abstraction?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, static, pool

I have the requirement to develop API in the format: https://api-domain.com/proxy/https://example.com which in turn
would load the specified website if visited from the browser using geo-targeted HTTP(S) proxy.

The problem is that we manage static proxy IP addresses ourselves so we need to assign any available proxy from the pool of managed (rented) proxies upon request. This way I am thinking about some sort of custom API logic, but I cannot find any good libraries/tools for this purpose in C# language.

Maybe someone could give any directions on how best it would be to implement such solution. Any tools/frameworks (preferably C#, .NET but any other language would be okay) ecosystem recommendations would be very much appreciated.